# Vertically center align all divs in a container using css

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `<div>`'s having different height which i want to be vertically center aligned inside their parent (with black background.) *Update-* As shown in the picture below

[image: Desired output]

HTML

```
<div style=" background-color:black; height:500px;width:500px;">  
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:red; height:400px;width:50px;">  </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:blue; height:300px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:green; height:200px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:yellow; height:100px;width:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcEL9.png)

Comment: then show an example of how you want?

Comment: Did you mean you want to vertically align the center points of inner `<divs>`? Please avoid using inline styles. it makes you're code unreadable and hard to wok with. [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: "I want all the div in the middle of black div." isn't clear. you can align the top, center, bottom etc at the center of container. please be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understood correctly, you can make use of [css3 flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) (*Assuming ancient browser support is not an issue*).

```
#container{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvevp/17/)

*Where `#container` is the `id` of parent `<div>` which you can see in demo*

Comment: It probably works on chrome only. EDIT: Now it works on Firefox.

Comment: @Linek i still have 5 minutes left to improve my answer :D

Comment: @Linek that's clearly mentioned in answer. hope you can read :)

Comment: I am sure he would never read the document you have provided link for. Just look at the question :D

Comment: @Linek i'm not talking about links. i've mentioned explicitly about browser support.

Comment: Can't disagree with that - maybe i'd start using the term *modern browsers* instead for supported browsers...

Comment: Flex box model is now supported in all major browsers with the exception of post versions of IE 10. Flex box is actually the correct way to achieve vertical align. It is why it was developed; so hacks would no longer be necessary.

Comment: Marked it as an answer.

Comment: @ManishGupta lol I spent 30 minutes writing up an article about using flexbox and you downvoted me. Tilwin writes display:flex; and gets answer marked as correct. Were is the justice? p.s I upvoted Tilwin.

Comment: Note this wont work in latest safari, safari mobile, IE 10, IE mobile or blackbery browser.

Comment: @Obsidion usually if two answers are similiar people accepts the first one (*there's an article in my answer too, and it's more official*)... but what do you mean this won't work in ie10 etc..? did you check the demo..? i just kept the browser prefixes away for keeping the answer simple and tempting ;) but i respect your effort and your answer brings the info right here hence upvoting it it..

Comment: @TilwinJoy Thank you for your comments. Your answer was the correct one and the one I voted for. My comment above was targeted at manish for downvoting me so no offence intended and good work.

Answer (score 2):

## Vertical Align using FlexBox

The newest technique to achieve this in css is using the flex box model.

**NOTES** Flex box is now supported on all major browsers and versions.
It will not however work on older version of Internet explorer post IE9.

### BROWSER SUPPORT
[image]

[CLICK FOR DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hvevp/22/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="Wrap" style=" background-color:black; height:500px;width:500px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:red; height:400px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:blue; height:300px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:green; height:200px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:yellow; height:100px;width:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Wrap{
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: @ManishGupta Seriously! Was a down vote really necessary? I am here to offer you help. Your here to offer critisism. This is not working because you are most likely using an outdated and no longer supported web browser. I was simply offering you a modern solution. P.s compatibility added to post.

Answer (score 1):

Use the vertical-align property of css

updated Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/aLL9t/

```
<div style=" background-color:black; height:500px;width:500px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:red; height:400px;width:50px;vertical-align:middle;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:blue; height:300px;width:50px;vertical-align:middle;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:green; height:200px;width:50px;vertical-align:middle;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:yellow; height:100px;width:50px;vertical-align:middle;"></div>
</div>
```

Link to read : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

UPDATE :
http://jsfiddle.net/aLL9t/1/

Comment: it isn't vertically aligning as far as i can see… there's space left at the bottom...

Comment: Many thanks for your time. Yes it is what I was saying.. But still there is space at the bottom. Please review it.

Comment: Now it is done, kindly see to it
Put display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle; to the parent div

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div style="height:400px;" class="red"></div>
        <div style="height:300px;" class="blue"></div>
        <div style="height:200px;" class="green"></div>
        <div style="height:100px;" class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: black;
}
#inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
#inner > div {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#inner > div.red {
    background: red;
}

#inner > div.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

#inner > div.blue {
    background: blue;
}

#inner > div.green {
    background: green;
}
```

`#inner` **must** have exactly the same height as the `#outer`. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvevp/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your post but this is not what I wanted. See updated question and see the marked answer.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the

```
display: inline-block;
```

from your styles and add these

```
float: left;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
position: relative;
left: 175px;
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/agDwx)

Comment: not at all working. I have marked the answer that I needed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your post but this is not what I wanted. See updated question and see the marked answer.